# comparion of scheduling algorithm on virtual machine and non virtal machine

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, scheduling

I want to compare  operating system process-scheduling algorithms- Round robin and FCFS scheduling algorithm for virtual machine and non virtual machine.

I found many articles for scheduling algorithm for non virtual machine regarding cloud computing. However I am not able to compare these algorithms in perspective of virtual and non virtual algorithms. Please suggest me where can i find the comparison or which algorithm will be efficient on both the machines.

Comment: What makes you think that a scheduling algorithm would behave differently on a virtual machine than on a non-virtual machine?

Comment: scheduling alogorithms are transparent to virtualization... you run linux on native machine or in VMWare scheduling algorithms will behave in same way.